# ArcGIS JavaScript API - Draw without Using API Toolbar Widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

ArcGIS API for JavaScript is using ESRI Toolbar Widget to handle Drawing like Point on the maps. Here is the [Demo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=toolbar_draw) doing this job.

Now my question is, is there a way to not use the `"esri/toolbars/draw"` facilities (Widget) and draw on the Graphic Layer by using core API coding?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
In the [Demo](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=toolbar_draw) page, add this few lines after map.on("load", createToolbar):

```
    map.on("click", addGraphic);

    function addGraphic(evt) {
      var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
      var graphic = new Graphic(evt.mapPoint, symbol);
      map.graphics.add(graphic);
      alert("Graphic added without the draw toolbar");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lele3p, can we also use same mechanism and other Geometry like line , Polyline, Polygon,.. ?